Animated Movie from late 70's to mid 80's
I'm trying to remember a movie that I saw when I was a little kid. All I remember is a scene where there are these dinosaur like creatures (I think) riding motorcycles that had wheels made of stone, and their roads were made of inflated rubber. Their world was basically the complete opposite of ours. I think it was animated, and probably made in the late 70's to possibly mid 80's judging from what I can remember of the style. Sorry for the lack of details. I probably haven't seen this movie since I was about 4 or 5. Thanks for any answers.

This sounds like an episode of Darkwing Duck (1991) Disney cartoon
The episode is called "Extinct Possibility"

After Darkwing, Launchpad and Gosalyn we're sent back to the Jurassic area, Johnny T Rex challenged them to a drag race.

Here's a clip of it on Youtube: 


The race starts around 14:40 (you can see the stone wheels and rubbery road)

Thanks. I honestly thought it was a movie but after watching the clip it does look exactly like I remember. This has been bugging me for long. Thank you again!
